# Use a jQuery instruction for main div, except a child div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div width `id="main"`.
I want that when clicked, its body background changes to black.

I do that by this code:

```
$("#main").click(function(){
    $("body").css("background", "#000");
});
```

I have another div with `id="second"` in div with `id="main"`:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="second">
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't want body background to change when I click div with `id="second"`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/JpjF9/2/).

```
$("#second").click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});​
```

Comment: Please test properly before posting. There is a typo that prevents it from working.

Comment: It really is a mystery why your original code works in Chrome (I just tested it myself).

Comment: @nhahtdh. Like IE, event is on the window object in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to block only child with id second then you can do this way,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KTEJk/)**

```
$("#main").click(function(event){
  if(event.target.id != "second")
  {   
       $("body").css("background", "#000");
  }
});
```

Comment: This blocks all children, not just #second.

Comment: [Now it allows clicking children](http://jsfiddle.net/KTEJk/1/) of #second. See my answer.

Comment: @flem Question does not states that second he children.

Comment: Example in question can be assumed as a contrived example. The point I'm making is that although your solution works, it is not very thorough.

Comment: Yes but if questioner learns the technique then it will be not be a problem to handle such a things.